# Issue with displaying admob ads

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I had been using admob ads perfectly fine until recently when I decided to run house ads, and then after those stopped it seems like admob turned off all my ads, on their website it shown 0 impressions. When I run the app and an ad request is called this is what the logcat displays:

```
02-06 17:27:46.757: ERROR/Ads(9298): AdLoader can't parse gWhirl server configuration.
02-06 17:27:46.757: INFO/Ads(9298): The following was caught and handled:
    org.json.JSONException: No value for ad_networks
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
    at com.google.ads.c.a(SourceFile:102)
    at com.google.ads.internal.c.b(SourceFile:994)
    at com.google.ads.internal.c.run(SourceFile:902)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
02-06 17:27:46.757: INFO/Ads(9298): onFailedToReceiveAd(There was an internal error.)
```

This is how my ads are called:

```
AdmobAd.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

is this some kind of problem with admob, or is there something I can do to fix it? I had no luck at all in finding contact info for admob on their website. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you can try at https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-admob-ads-sdk